# VBA - Copy Range and Paste to new sheet, shifting Entire Rows down?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to address the code highlighted in Bold, starting at "With ShNew." I take the range, copy columns A:B to LastRow, and insert them into a "Sh3" at the Last row. Sh3 last row is a Total row, everytime I run the code, it inserts the pasted data, but overwrites my total row (last row). I need to insert all the rows, and shift "Total" row down, and the ShiftXLDown, doesn't seem to work either.

```
Dim R1 As Range, R2 As Range, Sh1 As Worksheet, Sh2 As Worksheet, ShNew As Worksheet, sh3 As Worksheet, c As Range
    Dim ct As Long, lstrow As Long, lstrow2 As Long
    Dim copyProjects As Range

    Set Sh1 = Sheets("Monthly Actuals")
    Set Sh2 = Sheets("Week 4 - Demand")
    Set sh3 = Sheets("Monthly Pacing Report by Week")
    Set R1 = Sh1.Range("D5:D" & Sh1.Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row)
    Set R2 = Sh2.Range("A2:A" & Sh2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Sheets("New Sheet").Delete
On Error GoTo 0
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add.Name = "New Sheet"
Set ShNew = Worksheets("New Sheet")
For Each c In R2
    If IsError(Application.Match(c.Value, R1, 0)) Then
        ct = ct + 1
        Sh2.Rows(c.Row).Copy ShNew.Rows(ct)
    End If
Next c

With sh3
lstrow = sh3.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 1
.Range("A" & lstrow).Insert Shift:=xlDown
End With

**With ShNew
lstrow2 = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set copyProjects = .Range("A1:B" & lstrow2)
copyProjects.Copy Destination:=sh3.Range("A" & lstrow).Offset(1, 0)
End With**


With Application
    .DisplayAlerts = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With
```

Comment: FYI - you need to fully qualify the sheet when using `Range()`, `Cells()`, `Rows`, `Columns`. So, for example, this line: `lstrow2 = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` should be `lstrow2 = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: Thanks Bruce! I ended up figuring out a way to insert the rows and paste the data, Would you mind looking at the newly posted Solution? I use a loop, and insert rows, then paste. Feel like it could be optimized better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try this little refactoring of your code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim R1 As Range, c As Range
    Dim ShNew As Worksheet
    Dim ct As Long, lstrow As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Sheets("New Sheet").Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add.Name = "New Sheet"
    Set ShNew = Worksheets("New Sheet")

    With Sheets("Monthly Actuals")
        Set R1 = .Range("D5:D" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row)
    End With

    With Worksheets("Week 4 - Demand")
        For Each c In .Range("A2:A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
            If IsError(Application.Match(c.Value, R1, 0)) Then
                ct = ct + 1
                .Rows(c.Row).Copy ShNew.Rows(ct)
            End If
        Next c
    End With

    With Worksheets("Monthly Pacing Report by Week")
        lstrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("A" & lstrow).Resize(ct).EntireRow.Insert xlShiftUp
        ShNew.Range("A1:B" & ct).Copy Destination:=.Range("A" & lstrow)
    End With

    With Application
        .DisplayAlerts = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End Sub
```

however:

- all that copying/pasting around sheets is quite time consuming

  if you have sufficiently big amounts of data then you'd better resolve to use arrays
- concern *Sh3 last row is a Total row*

  if there resides a formula addressing the cells above it, then inserting rows right above it would not have that formula automatically extend its operating range

Comment: I posted a Solution that I think works as a new comment, Would you mind checking it and providing any feedback?

Comment: Just reviewed over your solution, thanks for showing me how to clean up my code and paste the data easier. This seems a lot better than my solution I posted below

Comment: you may then want to accept it! As to your new code, if it's a working code and you want it to be optimized then post it to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

**Solution Currently that I have found:**

Basically at the end of the code, I loop x amount of rows from the sheet, and insert those rows into my destination sheet. From there the destination sheet will have newly empty rows, to which I paste my ranges.

```
Dim R1 As Range, R2 As Range, Sh1 As Worksheet, Sh2 As Worksheet, ShNew As Worksheet, sh3 As Worksheet, c As Range
Dim ct As Long, lstrow As Long, lstrow2 As Long
Dim copyProjects As Range
Dim Rngcount As Range, row As Range
Set Sh1 = Sheets("Monthly Actuals")
Set Sh2 = Sheets("Week 4 - Demand")
Set sh3 = Sheets("Monthly Pacing Report by Week")
Set ShNew = Worksheets("New Sheet")
Set R1 = Sh1.Range("D5:D" & Sh1.Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).row)
Set R2 = Sh2.Range("A2:A" & Sh2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row)
Set Rngcount = ShNew.Range("A:A")
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Sheets("New Sheet").Delete
On Error GoTo 0
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add.Name = "New Sheet"
Set ShNew = Worksheets("New Sheet")
For Each c In R2
    If IsError(Application.Match(c.Value, R1, 0)) Then
        ct = ct + 1
        Sh2.Rows(c.row).Copy ShNew.Rows(ct)
    End If
Next c


With ShNew
For Each row In Rngcount
lstrow = sh3.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row + 1
If row > 0 Then
sh3.Range("A" & lstrow).EntireRow.Insert
End If
Next row
'
lstrow2 = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
Set copyProjects = .Range("A1:B" & lstrow2)
copyProjects.Copy
sh3.Range("A" & lstrow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
End With

With Application
    .DisplayAlerts = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With
```